# React relay string being read as enum on connection filter

Tags: reactjs, relay

I have this `paginationFragment`, which needs to accept a context var as a filter.  I have confirmed that the type is string using  `console.log('type', typeof dispContext, 'value', dispContext)` which returns `string`, and the string is simple, like `"ALL`.  Then I try to pass that string into my `filter`, using `filters: [dispContext]`.  I then get an error saying `argument 'filters[0]' with value 'EnumValue{name='dispContext'}' is not a valid 'String' - Expected AST type 'StringValue' but was 'EnumValue`

What is the mistake i am overlooking?  Here is my paginationfragment

```
 const {
data,
loadNext,
loadPrevious,
hasNext,
hasPrevious,
isLoadingNext,
isLoadingPrevious,
refetch, // For refetching connection
} = usePaginationFragment(
graphql`
  fragment TableListComponent_advisor on Advisor
  @refetchable(queryName: "AdvisorDashboardAssignmentsQuery")
  @argumentDefinitions(
    count: { type: "Int", defaultValue: 20 }
    cursor: { type: "String" }
  ) {
    assignments(first: $count, after: $cursor)
      @connection(key: "TableListComponent_advisor_assignments", 
      filters: [dispContext]) { <====== HERE IS PROBLEM <====
      edges {
        node {
          id
          ...TableRowComponent_lead
        }
      }
    }
  }
`,
advisor
 );
 const leads = data.assignments.edges;
```